# How to use my existing custom GTK theme (Arc) with gtk-window-decorator when using Compiz?

Tags: gtk, theme, compiz

I'm currently using Compiz 0.8 to get blur effects and transparency, in place of xfwm4. I had been using Emerald to provide window borders, but I was unhappy with the selection available there. I would prefer to use my GTK theme window borders (the ones I get when I run `xfwm4 --replace` in the terminal).

It turns out you can pass the command `gtk-window-decorator --replace` to use the standard GTK window borders. However, these use some sort of default theme that looks really out of place. I have no idea how to change it.

[image]

I'm running Arch Linux with XFCE. The Arch Linux wiki provided me with the same answer that a lot of other pages did - to use gsettings to change some entries. This didn't work, probably because (as the wiki page says, albeit without any elaboration) that Compiz-reloaded, the project that represents the continued maintenance of the Compiz 0.8 project, have switched to using Marco instead of Metacity.

So that leaves me at a loss. The change was rather recent, and Compiz is pretty far past its prime, so I can't find much on how to deal with this issue with the recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is the fix:

1. Install marco-gtk2 from the AUR
2. Remove your old core package (it can be compiz-core, compiz-gtk, compiz-core-git or compiz-gtk-git)
3. install compiz-gtk or compiz-gtk-git (depending on whether you use the stable or latest release of compiz-reloaded) but edit the PKGBUILD so the line the value of _use_marco (at the top of the file) is 2.
4. Enjoy!